# Delay items emission until item is emitted from another observable

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

Playing with RxJava now and stumbled upon the following problem:

I have 2 different streams:

- Stream with items
- Stream (with just 1 item) which emits transformation information for the first stream.

So essentially I have stream of items and I want all those items to be combined with that single item from 2nd stream:

----a1----a2----a3----a4----a5----|--------------->

-------------b1--|----------------------------------->

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

------------a1b1-a2b1-a3b1-a4b1-a5b1-------->

It looks really similar to [`combileLatest`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) operator, but combineLatest will ignore all items from the first stream except the closest to the item from the second stream. It means that I will not receive `a1b1` - the first resulting item emitted is gonna be `a2b1`.

I also looked at [`delay`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#delay(rx.functions.Func1)) operator, but it doesn't allow me to specify `close` stream like it is done with [`buffer`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#buffer(rx.functions.Func0)) operatior

Is there any fancy operator which solves the problem above?

Comment: Will the combination of `cache`, `repeat` and `zip` work for you? Something like http://pastebin.com/BjPmDBWw

Comment: Ooops, that was a bad idea because first observable emits much more items than I thought. Something is wrong with backpressure...

Comment: yeah.. `cache().repeat()` indefinitely repeats single item which is not the best idea for your backpressure..

Comment: Second try! http://pastebin.com/RZLZfMk6

Comment: it seems to be working :) Now I need to understand WHY it works :) In the meantime - you can post this as an answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no a built-in operator to achieve the behavior you've described. You can always implement a custom operator or build it on top of existing operators. I think the second option is easier to implement and here is the code:

```
public static <L, R, T> Observable<T> zipper(final Observable<? extends L> left, final Observable<? extends R> right, final Func2<? super L, ? super R, ? extends T> function) {
    return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<T>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<T> call() {
            final SerialSubscription subscription = new SerialSubscription();
            final ConnectableObservable<? extends R> cached = right.replay();

            return left.flatMap(new Func1<L, Observable<T>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<T> call(final L valueLeft) {
                    return cached.map(new Func1<R, T>() {
                        @Override
                        public T call(final R valueRight) {
                            return function.call(valueLeft, valueRight);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).doOnSubscribe(new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    subscription.set(cached.connect());
                }
            }).doOnUnsubscribe(new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    subscription.unsubscribe();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

If you have any questions regarding the code, I can explain it in details.

**UPDATE**

Regarding the questing how my solution is different from the following one:

```
left.flatMap(valueLeft -> right.map(valueRight -> together(valueLeft, valueRight)));
```

1. Parallel execution - in my implementation both `left` and `right` observables are executing in parallel. `right` observable doesn't have to wait for a `left` one to emit its first item.
2. Caching - my solution subscribes only once to the `right` observables and caches its result. Thats why `b1` will always be the same for all `aXXX` items. The solution provided by [akarnokd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30234087/1950649) subscribes to the `right`observable every time the `left` one emits an item. That means:

   - There is no guarantee that `b1` won't change its value. For example for the following observable you will get a different `b` for each `a`.

     ```
     final Observable<Double> right = Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Double>>() {
         @Override
         public Observable<Double> call() {
             return Observable.just(Math.random());
         }
     });
     ```
   - If the `right` observable is a time consuming operation (e.g. network call), you will have to wait for its completion every time the `left` observable emits a new item.

Comment: There is a race condition regarding subscription in your example. If the downstream unsubscribes while the left.flatMap.doOnSubscribe.doOnUnsubscribe is being subscribed to, the doOnUnsubscribe executes before the doOnSubscribe is able to set the Subscription and thus throw an NPE. The correct way to do this is to use SerialSubscription for subscription and call subscription.unsubscribe() directly in doOnUnsubscribe.

Comment: @akarnokd thanks! I thought such situation is impossible to happen.

Comment: @VladimirMironov could you please explain a bit what's the difference between `left.flatMap(valueLeft -> right.map(valueRight -> together(valueLeft, valueRight)));` and your extended version?

Comment: as far as I can see the main difference is that stream `b` (the right one) is subscribed right away - it doesn't wait for emission from stream `a`. is that right?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of making this happen:

1) `flatMap` over `b` if you don't need to start `a` upfront

```
b.flatMap(bv -> a.map(av -> together(av, bv)));
```

2) You can, of course, `cache` but it will retain your `a`s for the entire duration of the stream.

3) Use groupBy a bit unconventionally because its GroupedObservable caches values until the single subscriber arrives, replays the cached value and continues as a regular direct observable (letting all previous cached values go).

```
Observable<Long> source = Observable.timer(1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("Tick"))
        .take(10);
Observable<String> other = Observable.just("-b").delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("Tack"))
        ;

source.groupBy(v -> 1)
.flatMap(g -> 
    other.flatMap(b -> g.map(a -> a + b))
).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
```

It works as follows:

- Get a hold onto a `GroupedObservable` by grouping everything from source into group 1.
- when the group `g` arrives, we 'start observing' the other observable.
- Once other fires its element, we take it and map it over the group and 'start observing' it as well, bringing us the final sequence of `a + b`s.

I've added doOnNexts so you can see the source is really active before the `other` fires its "Tack".

Comment: I really liked your first solution.. mostly because I don't quite understand the other two :) just starting with Rx.. lots of new cool stuff to learn